# Get Selected Item from Context Menu

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, stackpanel

I am creating a set of images dynamically and putting them into a Stack Panel like this :-

```
            Image image = new Image();
            image.Name = "image_" + iCounter;
            image.Height = 100;
            image.Width = 100;
            image.Source = bitmap;
            image.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            image.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
            image.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            //image.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(image_MouseDown);
            image.ToolTip = "Right-Click for Options";
            image.ContextMenu = GetContextMenu();

            Separator separator = new Separator();
            separator.Name = "separator_" + iCounter;

            AddImagesStackPanel.Children.Add(image);
            AddImagesStackPanel.Children.Add(separator);

            iCounter++;
```

Then in the Context Menu I have this code :-

```
    private System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu GetContextMenu()
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem mi1;
        System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem mi2;
    
        System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu _contextMenu = new System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu();
    
        mi1 = new System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem();
        mi1.Header = "Show Normal Size";
        mi1.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(ContextMenuItem1_Click);

        mi2 = new System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem();
        mi2.Header = "Remove image";
        mi2.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(ContextMenuItem2_Click);

        _contextMenu.Items.Add(mi1);
        _contextMenu.Items.Add(mi2);
        return _contextMenu;
    }
```

Now I wish to get the selected item when the user right clicks on an image and I have this code :-

```
    private void ContextMenuItem2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        object obj = e.OriginalSource;

        string imageName = ((System.Windows.Controls.Image)obj).Name;
        string[] split = imageName.Split('_');
        imageUploads.RemoveAt(Convert.ToInt32(split[1]));
        DisplayImagesInStackPanel(imageUploads);
    }
```

But obj does not contain the name of the image since its a RoutedEventArgs.  Is there any way I can get the selected item in the context menu?

Comment: Considering that you are using WPF i'd recommend you do not add images as static content but bind your controls to a collection of images instead.

Comment: Hi HB, can you tell me exactly what you mean by binding the controls to a collection of images?  You mean putting the images in a List<Imagges> and then binding it to the panel?

Comment: I would use the most high-level class possible, i.e. you could have a list of ImageSources or URLs and create the images automatically using [DataTemplating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx). Also you would want to use an ObservableCollection<T> if the list changes.

Comment: yeah good suggestion but would that help in getting the actual ID-Name from the context menu?

Comment: What ID-Name? What do you need that for?

Comment: I just want the details of the image that I right click on, so that I can remove/enlarge and the context menu does not include that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After discussing this in the comments this should work:

```
// The binding source.
private readonly ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> _imageList = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();
public ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> ImageList
{
    get { return _imageList; }
}
```

How to display this and set up the ContextMenu:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ImageList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding}" Width="100" Height="100"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stretch="Fill"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" ToolTip="Right-Click for Options">
                    <Image.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Show Normal Size" Click="Image_CM_ShowNormalSize_Click"
                                      Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget}"/> <!-- The placement target is the object to which the context menu belongs, i.e. the image -->
                            <MenuItem Header="Remove Image" Click="Image_CM_RemoveImage_Click"
                                      Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext}"/> <!-- The DataContext of the Image is the BitmapImage, which should be removed from the list -->
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Image.ContextMenu>
                </Image>
                <Separator/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

What the handlers might look like:

```
private void Image_CM_ShowNormalSize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Image img = (sender as FrameworkElement).Tag as Image;
    img.Width = (img.Source as BitmapImage).PixelWidth;
    img.Height = (img.Source as BitmapImage).PixelHeight;
}

private void Image_CM_RemoveImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BitmapImage img = (sender as FrameworkElement).Tag as BitmapImage;
    // If the image is removed from the bound list the respective visual elements
    // will automatically be removed as well.
    ImageList.Remove(img);
}
```

Comment: Hi HB, I tried your code, but the images are not being bound to the ItemsControl.  The ImageList is being populated, but no response in the ItemsControl.  Do I need to bind to it? Or is it supposed to bind automatically once the list is populated?

Comment: Ok got it to work!  I had to add this             ImageList = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();
            DataContext = this;
 to the Initialize Code.  Thanks for your help HB

Answer (score 0):

> But obj does not contain the name of the image since its a RoutedEventArgs.

True, but the `obj` at that point is a `MenuItem`, if you drill one level down, you can get the image.

> Is there any way I can get the selected item in the context menu?

Normally one would load the model classes (Image in your case) through the binding of `ItemSource` of the Menu (or `MenuItem` if they are to be submenus) and if one takes that route they can pull the originating item off of the `DataContext` such as in my case the item was an `MRU` class item.

```
private void SelectMRU(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var mru = (e.OriginalSource as MenuItem).DataContext as MRU;
    var name = mru.Name;
    ...
}
```

Because you do things by hand you should load the `Tag` property of the `MenuItem` with the `Image` in question

```
 mi1.Tag = {Image instance in question};
```

then extract on the event.

```
 var image = (e.OriginalSource as MenuItem).Tag as Image;
```